# HTML webpage with all css in Angular app

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and trying to resolve problem concerning displaying HTML website in my Angular application.
The webpages with all resources like images, css files etc. are stored on external server. Sites contain text, images, own styles, css etc. Everythink works fine when I open such website in web browser. When I trying to display such page inside my application a lot of problems aren't resolved.

I used innerHtml to diplay page in application:

```
<div [innerHtml]="content"></div>
```

All links are being changed to be direct before displaying. Text and images display but styles aren't applied. Maybe the problem is connected with the fact that links to .css are located in <"head> block?

Hope sb had problem like me and can help :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to use a Sanitizer (https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to [Sanitize](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) (Please read the documentation from Angular about what it means to use a `DomSanitizer`) your html before putting it inside the html.

In your component, inject DomSanitizer, and bypass security:

```
safeContent;
constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){
    const content = "your html";
    this.safeContent = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
}
```

and in your html:

```
<div [innerHtml]="safeContent"></div>
```

Comment: Ok now it works, but styles are applied to all elements in my appllication. It is possible to apply these styles only to HTML returned from server?
The application consist of menu, other elements and window where I decided to display the HTML from server. When I used DomSanitazer HTML content is displayed in a correct way, but styles are also applied to other elements in the application.

Comment: According to my comment above. `ViewEncapsulation.Native` make it possible and styles aren't applied to rest of application.